# Функция. Почему мы пишем 0 в temps[0]?

Tags: javascript

Функция для вычисления амплитуды температуры. Почему мы пишем 0 в temps[0]?

```
const temperatures = [3, -2, -6, -1, "error", 9, 13, 17, 15, 14, 9, 5];

const calcTempAmplitude = function (temps) {
    let max = temps[0];
    let min = temps[0];

    for(let i = 0; i < temps.length; i++) {
        const curTemp = temps[i];
        
        if(typeof curTemp !== "number") continue;

        if(curTemp > max) max = curTemp;
        
        if(curTemp < min) min = curTemp;
    }
    console.log(max, min);

    return max - min;
};

const amplitude = calcTempAmplitude(temperatures);

console.log(amplitude);
```

Comment: Где это туда пишется ноль?

Comment: let max = temps[0];
 let min = temps[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нахождения минимума и максимума путем сравнения нужно какое-то опорное значение. Значение первого (с нулевым индексом) элемента массива вполне подходит.

Иногда используются заведомо экстремальные значения, например, для начального значения минимума - Maxint  или другая подобная константа